# android studio can't find java sdk after invalidate caches... even after reinstall

Tags: java, android

I had minor problems in a project I was working on and use invalidate caches and clean to see if that would help. However that did something not just to that one project but to android studio in general. it does not recognize java, the appearance of even the home screen has changed. I can't start any new projects in java and none of the old work. Strangely, even after I uninstalled both studio and java and then reinstalled the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear Android Studio cache, assuming you're using v3.3, delete the cache folder located at:

```
C:\Users\your_username\.AndroidStudio3.3\system\caches
```

Answer (score 0):

incompatibility between the Android Studio cache and your current project layout. If you suspect this is the problem, then select `File> Cache / Restart> Validate and Restart` from the Android Studio toolbar.
To set JDK location: you can see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jA97GYqRODE